# How to populate data into the FormGroup?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, formarray, formgroups

I am trying to populate data into the 'technologies' form group, but unable to do that;

Here is:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fzgtqc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts **(Reproducible Example)**

```
editTrainner(trainner: Trainner) {
    this._trainnerservice.currentTrainner = Object.assign({}, trainner);
    this.registrationForm.patchValue({
          personal_details: { type: Object,
            name: { type: Object,
                first_name:this._trainnerservice.currentTrainner.personal_details.name.first_name,
                last_name: this._trainnerservice.currentTrainner.personal_details.name.last_name
            },
            dob: this._trainnerservice.currentTrainner.personal_details.dob,
            about_yourself: this._trainnerservice.currentTrainner.personal_details.about_yourself,
            willingly_to_travel: this._trainnerservice.currentTrainner.personal_details.willingly_to_travel
        }
    });
    this.addlanguages_known();
    this.addTechs();
  }
  addlanguages_known(): any {
    const control = this.registrationForm.get('personal_details.languages_known') as FormArray;
    this._trainnerservice.currentTrainner.personal_details.languages_known.forEach(x => {
        control.push(this.fb.control(x));
      });
  }

  addTechs(): any {
    const control =  this.registrationForm.get('technologies') as FormArray;
    console.log(control);
    this._trainnerservice.currentTrainner.technologies.forEach(x => {
      control.push(this.fb.control(x));
    });
  }
```

Comment: hi can please tell me where you getting issue in this

Comment: @harkeshkumar i have created a function addTechs() its not loading data into the form, earlier i have created function addlanguages_known() its working but addTechs() not working

Comment: what is inside x?

Comment: so this add techs fx will add formgroup right or you want to do something else or where u getting in it

Comment: see I have created one more function  addlanguages_known() in this with help of 'x' i populating the data, similarly, I am trying  to do with addTechs()

Comment: only difference is languages_known is form array and technologies is a formGroup.

Comment: but when u click on add technologies button it repeating from so what is your issue

Comment: see there is a data, so when user will click on the edit button, edittrainner() function will be executed and the main objective behind executing this function is it will load the data of a particular user into the form so that user can edit and update his details

Comment: you will find the sample data into the app.component.ts file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular provides the ability to initialize your `FormGroup` on creation. I would suggest you initialize the values when you create `registrationForm` like below.

```js
this.registrationForm = this.fb.group({
    ...
    technologies: this.fb.array(
        this.data.technologies && this.data.technologies.length ? 
            this.data.technologies.map(tech => this.addTech(tech)) : [this.addTech()]
    ),
    ...
});

addTech(tech: Technology = {costing: {}} as Technology): FormGroup {
    return this.fb.group({
        name: [tech.name || ''],
        experience : [tech.experience || ''],
        ratings : [tech.ratings || ''],
        costing :  this.fb.group({
            freshers: [tech.costing.freshers || ''],
            laterals : [tech.costing.laterals || ''],
            project_specific: [tech.costing.project_specific || '']
        }),
        work_as_consultant: [tech.work_as_consultant || '']
    });
}
```

where your `Technology` interface would look something like this

```js
export interface Technology {
    name: string;
    experience: number;
    ratings: number;
    costing: Costing;
    work_as_consultant: string;
}

export interface Costing {
    freshers: number;
    laterals: number;
    project_specific: number;
}
```

Similarly, create interfaces for your other form groups and initialize them on creation as shown above.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `patchValue` instead of pushing values into `control`. Form controls should be added to `formArray`, when you need more controls to be added to the form itself.

```
this.registrationForm.patchValue({
  technologies: this._trainnerservice.currentTrainner.technologies
});
```

Comment: It havent worked for mutilple array. Check here : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fzgtqc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: check sample data also in that file.

Comment: That's because angular didnt find any controls to allocate that data. You need to add as many controls as the number of data items that you have. ` technologies: this.fb.array([
        this.addTech(),
        this.addTech(), //<--- this line here
      ]),` Looking at this solution, you should be able to determine the number of controls you need add for each data.

Answer (score 0):

```
ngOnInit() {


    this.registrationForm = this.fb.group({
      personal_details : this.fb.group({
        name: this.fb.group({
          first_name: [''],
          last_name: ['']
        }),
        about_yourself: [''],
        dob: [''],
        // lang: [''],
        languages_known: this.fb.array([]),
        willingly_to_travel: ['']
      }),
      technologies: this.fb.array([
        this.addTech()
      ]),

      certifications : this.fb.array([
        this.addCertificate()
      ]),
    });
    // this.getAllTrainners();
    this.editTrainner();

     this.registrationForm.patchValue({
      technologies: this._trainnerservice.currentTrainner.technologies
});
```

Comment: is this going to work for multiple arrays of technologies formgroup ?

Comment: yes but have to pass the value ( technology array) it will show